# python numpy нормализовать двумерный массив с помощью .mean и .std

Tags: python, математика, numpy

Есть такая задачка:

> В задачах машинного обучения часто требуется нормализовать данные
> перед тем, как их использовать. Пусть в переменной `X` находится
> двумерный `np.array`, по строкам которого записаны разные объекты, а
> по столбцам — признаки. Вам необходимо написать функцию
> `normalize(X)`, принимающую на вход массив `X` и нормализующий все
> переменные таким образом, чтобы их среднее равнялось 0, а стандартное
> отклонение 1. Иными словами, для каждого столбца необходимо из всех
> элементов вычесть среднее по этому столбцу и результат разделить на
> стандартное отклонение по этому столбцу. Более формально: если
> $X=(x_{ij})$ — наша матрица, $x_{ij}$ — элемент, который стоит в её
> $i$-й строке и $j$-м столбце, и $x_{\cdot j}$ — $j$-й столбец, то в
> новой матрице на $i$-й строке в $j$-м столбце будет стоять элемент
>
> $$\widehat{x}*{ij}=\frac{x*{ij}-\overline{x_{\cdot
> j}}}{\sigma_{x_{\cdot j}}},$$ где $\overline{x_{\cdot j}}$ —
> выборочное среднее (среднее арифметическое) всех элементов $j$-го
> столбца, $\sigma_{x_{\cdot j}}$ — стандартное отклонение всех
> элементов $j$-го столбца.
>
> **Подсказка.** Вычислить среднее можно с помощью метода `.mean()`, стандартное отклонение — с помощью `.std()`. Обе функции принимают на
> вход параметр `axis`, с помощью которого можно применять их к строкам
> или столбцам двумерного массива. Использовать циклы, как обычно,
> запрещено. Задачу можно решить в одну строчку.

Пробую решить ее, придерживаясь условия: `без циклов` и в одну строку.

Мое решение:

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
def normalize(x):
    return (x - x.mean(axis=0)) / x.std(axis=0)
print(normalize(x))
```

Вывод:

```
[[-1.22474487 -1.22474487 -1.22474487]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.22474487  1.22474487  1.22474487]]
```

Кажется, что все сходится, а конкретно, что среднее арифметическое равно 0 и квадратное отклонение равно 1 (для столбцов)

Подскажите, пожалуйстa, правильно ли я делаю?

Comment: да, похоже, что правильно. если вас смущает, верно ли работает векторный функционал numpy (column-wise subtraction), вы всегда можете сделать быструю проверку на срезе, например (`(x[:,0] - np.mean(x[:,0]))/np.std(x[:,0])`)

Comment: Возможно, что следует установить в функции std параметр  ddof...